# Ruby loses millisecond somewhere

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to add milliseconds for some timestamps. It seems that there are some milliseconds getting lost somewhere.

```
input:    00:00:36,040
expected: 00:00:37,040
output:   00:00:37,039
```

Any ideas?

```
puts Timestamp.new("00:00:36,040").add("1,000").to_string

class Timestamp

  def initialize(instr)
     h, m, s, l = instr.split(/[:,]/).map { |x| x.to_i }
     @time = Time.at(h*3600 + m*60 + s + l*0.001 ) - Time.new.utc_offset
  end

  def to_string
    @time.strftime("%H:%M:%S,%L")
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't call the `add` method in you example, it is not clear why it is there, nor how you processed the input to get the output. Please include enough code to replicate your result.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated it there now. Thanks for taking the time to look.

Comment: Better, thanks. But I still cannot see how you get the string output - and this could be important (I suspect a Float rounding error maybe requiring a change to how you handle milliseconds).

Comment: You're mistaken, @steenslag. `String#to_i` defaults to base 10, and `"040".to_i` will return `40`, as expected. (If OP was doing `040.to_i` it would be a different story.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely being caught by one of the oldest problems in computing, [floating point inaccuracies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

```
$ ruby -e 'puts 3723.004.class'
Float

$ ruby -e 'puts Time.at(3723.004).strftime("%H:%M:%S,%L")'
17:02:03,003
```

Simply put, numbers like `3723.004` are not what they seem.  Computers store them very differently and it results in slight inaccuracies in odd places.  These inaccuracies can add up in calculations.

To work around this, stick to integers where possible.  [Use the two argument form of `Time.at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Time.html#method-c-at) (note: it takes *micro*seconds).

```
$ ruby -e 'puts Time.at(3723, 4000).strftime("%H:%M:%S,%L")'
17:02:03,004
```

Comment: Actually I think I have found a different culprit than Float rounding . . .

Comment: @NeilSlater Yes, there may be other problems with the OP's code.

Comment: Great answer. FWIW you can also give `Time.at` a Rational, e.g. `Time.at(h*3600 + m*60 + s + Rational(l, 1000))`.

Comment: Actually no, I just been checking - was wondering about the two calls to `Time`, but `Time#utc_offset` didn't do what I thought . . . so I think this answer covers the whole of OP's issue